# How to call Promise inside Promise and call function 2 times at a time in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, angular-promise

My code scenario is like :-

```
async function ot(a: any) {
    return "outer text " + a;
}

async function it() {
    return "inner text";
}

function insert() {
    it().then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        ot(res).then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
        });
    });
}

insert();
insert();
```

**NOTE:- I have called insert() function 2 times**

Code output:-

```
"inner text" 
"inner text" 
"outer text inner text"
"outer text inner text"
```

expected output:-

```
"inner text"
"outer text inner text"
"inner text"
"outer text inner text"
```

I want to call insert function more then one time at a single time,
is there any way to reach it?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `then`

```js
async function ot(a) {
    return "outer text " + a;
}

async function it() {
    return "inner text";
}

function insert() {
    return it().then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return ot(res).then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
        });
    });
}

insert().then(() => insert());
```

Comment: A little explanation would suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much this answer was small and easy

Answer (score 0):

First of all, switch from `then` to `await`

```
async function it(): Promise<string> {
    return "inner text";
}
async function ot(a: string): Promise<string> {
    return "outer text " + a;
}
async function insert(): Promise<void> {
    let res = await it();
    console.log(res);
    let resp = await ot(res);
    console.log(resp);
}
insert();
insert();
```

What you want is to wait for the first function to end before the second starts, being

```
await insert()
insert()
```

which is correct but pauses the whole script for the first `insert` duration
To avoid that you can either

```
// I probably took that from js minifiers but I always void IIFEs
void async function() {
    await insert()
    insert()
}()
```

or

```js
insert().then(() => insert())
```

or

```js
insert().then(insert) // as insert has no args
```

Comment: this is working but i am more compatible with Konrad answer, Thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
async function insert() {
    const res = await it();
    console.log(res);
    const resp = ot(res);
    console.log(resp);
}
```

or, if you insist on using `then` chains,

```
function insert() {
    return it().then(res => {
//  ^^^^^^
        console.log(res);
        return ot(res).then(resp => {
//      ^^^^^^
            console.log(resp);
        });
    });
}
```

and then use the promise that `insert` returns for sequential execution through `await`

```
async function main() {
    await insert();
    await insert();
}
main().catch(console.error);
```

or through chaining:

```
insert().then(insert).catch(console.error);
```